# Swift 4 Unwind segue not working on navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am working on an app in Swift 4 and I am trying to unwind a segue. I have a Table View Controller, When the user selects a cell, the segue happens to a navigation controller which has a relationship root view controller with another controller I have `UIViewController`. In the `UIViewController` I have a `UIButton` inside Navigation Items, I have unwind set with the UIButton by selecting the button and dragging to exit and I have the unwind code inside the `UITableViewController` like so:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "segueRSVP" {
            }
        }



    @IBAction override func unwind(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, towardsViewController subsequentVC: UIViewController) {
        print("Here")
    }
```

But nothing happens, it doesn't even get triggered.

Here are my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put the tableview in the navigation controlller and then you won’t even need the unwind segue or the button.

Comment: You cant see in my screenshots, but there is a navigation controller above the tableview controller....so it goes navigation controller -> tableview -> navigation controller -> UIViewController

Comment: Then delete the second navigation controller and use a `show` segue to show the rsvp scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this unwind to your RSVP controller:

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("IM BACK")
}
```

Then control + drag the button in your detail controller up to the exit and select the method: unwindToThisViewController

Just tested this on xcode swift 4 and it should work

I'm not sure why, but when I "overrode" unwind, it didn't work for me either, so I set up my own ibaction

Comment: Oh hmm remove this: `override func prepare`. and remove `@IBAction override func unwind` and see if that does it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, was tagging the swift unwind func with `@objc` keyword.

```
@objc func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { ... }
```

Hope this works.