# Switching ViewControllers Starting From a PageController View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

[Image of my storyBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqbwa.png)

The flow to what I am trying to achieve is starting at the vc circled in green then moving to the one circled in blue then finally from blue go to red.

The green circled vc is a child of my pagecontroller vc (the page controller is part of a navcontroller - the page controller is positioned above green). Green also has a segue that when you click the cell in the table it displays the blue highlighted vc. Works fine.

The red circed vc is part of a nav controller and it has a segue to blue as well. Also works fine.

Basically within blue i have a button that allows me to display the content of what is in the red vc. This works fine going from red to blue and back again. But when im going from green to blue then red i cannot seem to get there.

I've tried instantiating a new vc but this means im making a new one and duplicates things. I simply want to display the content on red even if it is presented modally.

Please, if this question isn't making much sense let me know and i will try my best to add more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out how to do this using the unwind segue method. I did not even know that existed before.

I found this to help [unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209309/swift-4-unwind-segue-not-working-on-navigation-controller/47210582)